how to solve Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. while running flutter application
getting this error when running flutter application

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/anurag.patel.in/Desktop/flutter/bin/flutter''


Try this in terminal:
flutter clean
then go to pubspec.yaml file, try doing Pub get, and then build the project again.
